# Can anybody explain syntax

Tags: javascript

```
  const lastTick = this.xAxis[0].ticks[this.xAxis[0].tickPositions.length - 1];
  const { width } = lastTick.label.getBBox();
  const { chartWidth } = this;
  lastTick.label.attr({ x: chartWidth - (0.7) * width });
```

This is highcharts code. I want meaning of `{ width }` , `{ chartWidth }`.

Comment: This is Destructuring. `const { chartWidth } = this;` is just `const chartWidth = this.chartWidth;`

Answer (score -1):

It's called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It is similar to writing

```js
const chartWidth = this.chartWidth;
const width = lastTick.label.getBBox().width;
```

Comment: Not sure, but likely because you are answering an obvious duplicate question. Answering it again and again is not useful.

Comment: When I opened the question it was not clear to me that it was a duplicate (no votes yet) and the answer seemed legit as well. It seems off down voting the answer while not closing the question yet.

Comment: @RobAu so we can only tell it's a duplicate if someone else has voted to close it as a duplicate? How does that get started, how does the first person (hi!) figure it out? As a rule of thumb, if you think "that seems really obvious, I can't believe nobody has asked it before": they probably have, go find it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe *you* can probably tell easily; I never saw this before, clicked the link and learned something. But I get that if its obvious to the more experienced JS developer, it's a logical thing to do. Thanks for the clarification.